# Is it OK to ignore image title attributes when it comes to SEO?

Tags: seo, images, image-search

I've [read on Yoast](https://yoast.com/image-seo/) that it's OK to ignore the image `title`, but not the `alt` field from a SEO perspective.

However, the SEO expert in the company insist it's highly required for SEO.

Who is right?  Is there any reference or documentation for it?

Comment: Why not use it for users? Aren't they the reason why we build web pages in the first place? Shouldn't SEO be secondary to that? In fact, isn't a usable and accessible website SEO friendly by definition?

Comment: @JohnConde, I've read how important it's for users, but I want to know for sure if it's important for SEO "theoretically". Adding to that, he put a guide to follow in writing the title, which is appending the today's date for the title attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title tag can be ignored completely as long as you fill in the alt tag as far as image SEO is concerned.

As far as I have been able to figure out, Google has four sources for the text it associates with images:

- The `alt` image attribute
- The `title` image attribute
- The image URL file name
- Text within the `div` that contains the image (eg `<div><img src='...'> Text associated with the image.</div>`

Of the four, the text in the containing `div` seems to be the most powerful.  Google tends to like to index text that users can see.    I have had the best luck getting an image associated with text by enclosing both the image and the text directly in a `div`.

Then to get images to rank well, you need "high quality" images.   Google pretty much defines "high quality" as "large".   Generally, the more pixels in the image file, the better it will rank.